# express send incomplete response json data

Tags: json, node.js, express, response

The version info:
    "express": "~4.15.2",
    "express-session": "^1.15.5",

I use this code send large json data to client:

```
   router.get('/exportAllData',function(req,res,next){
    async function getData(){
    let sql="SELECT * FROM int_information "
    let rows=await query(sql);
    let data=await JSON.stringify(rows);
    return JSON.parse(data);
  }
  getData().then(data=>res.send({flag:1,data:data})).catch(error=>{
    res.send({flag:0,err:error});
  });  
})
```

I tried wget localhost on server and can get full data, 
But the remote client got broken json data and different each time refresh.
Where is the problem? Seems response closed before get all data.

Comment: Hello Ricky, when you mean remote client, is it a like a production environment? As in, not localhost, you can have networks delays, etc?
Do you have another webserver in front of express?

Comment: @lovethebomb Hello, yes, there is network delay between server and remote client caused this problem. There is no any other proxy in front of express. I can get full data if I use another client in the same LAN of server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an open bug in node js 8.x, I use 7.10 solved this problem.
Or you can set server.keepAliveTimeout=30000 in app.js to extend timeout setting